# How to link ".gram" file to pocketsphinx in C

Tags: c, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am pretty new to CMU Sphinx and I am trying to set some grammar rules to pocketsphinx in C.

I've found example on how to write a grammar file in JSGF format. Something like this.

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar hello;
public <greet> = (good morning | hello) ( bob | juli );
```

and to save it as ".gram" file extension.

But I am not able to find how to link it to the recognizer so that it follows these grammar rules.

Also a big question being, is this syntax correct for C language too? Cuz we don't have these access specifiers in C.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found this simple solution after a lot of research.

We just have to include the grammar file (.gram or .jsgf) during the configuration using "-jsgf" tag.

like this

```
config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
"-hmm", "<here comes path to our acoustic model>",
"-dict", "<path to dictionary>",
"-jsgf", "grammarTest.jsgf",
NULL);
```